# Google Chrome on 1440p Monitor on Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, screen-resolution, hdpi

I basically tried everything and searched everywhere, but I can't make google chrome "scale" at the res of 1440p. All the things (Websites as well as UI) are way to small to read and use comfortably. I tried to edit the registry, enable chrome flags that are apparently not available anymore and modify the shortcut start parameters. What am I doing wrong?

(Windows is scaled to a 125%)
(Firefox, Opera and IE scale perfectly btw)

Comment: In less recent versions, there was an hidpi flag in `chrome://flags`. Now a days the option needs to be set outside of the browser. Check [this](http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/how-to-google-chrome-hidpi-support-windows/) out.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPullar for the help
I tried it, and it didn't work, sadly